# How to change system.webServer/defaultDocument in web.config programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-4.0

I am trying to access `system.webServer/defaultDocument` in my web.config file but can't seem to find out how. I have tried various articles about editing the web config file but I don't seem to have the same options to access the items in `system.webServer` as I would if I was changing a connectionString for instance.

I can load the system.webServer section using:

```
ConfigurationSection WebServerSection = (ConfigurationSection)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.webServer");
```

but can't see to find anything usable from that point. One thing I have noticed is that the `system.webServer` section is of type `System.Configuration.IgnoreSection`. Does this somehow stop me having access to edit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look the [Microsoft.Web.Administration API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), it offers a [WebConfigurationManager class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.webconfigurationmanager%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that should allow you to access the content of the webServer section:

```
WebConfigurationManager.GetSection(HttpContext.Current,
  "system.webServer/defaultDocument");
```

Comment: I can't seem to find the Microsoft.Web.Administration Namespace to use in my website. Where is it located?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it in `%windir%\syswow64\inetsrv`. I am also looking at this article which seems to cover it in line with this DLL. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabh_singh/archive/2007/11/24/accessing-iis-7-0-features-programmatically-from-configuration-file-s-c.aspx Thanks.